# how to know the id of server control inside the ItemTemplate of a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

QUESTION: How can I bind the visibility of FixHyperLink to the condition that Label1 has a non-empty text value?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Error" SortExpression="Error">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Error") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="FixHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("AppID", "~/da/Default2.aspx?appid={0}") %>'>Fix</asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

UPDATE: C# version of answer

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var l = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
            var h = (HyperLink)row.FindControl("FixHyperLink");
            h.Visible = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to identify the index of the row you want to change then get it like this:

```
        Dim tempRow As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow
    Dim tempLabel As Label
    Dim tempHyperlink As HyperLink

    For Each tempRow In GridView1.Rows
        tempLabel = CType(tempRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
        tempHyperlink = CType(tempRow.FindControl("FixHyperLink"), HyperLink)
        If tempLabel.Text.Trim <> String.Empty Then
            tempHyperlink.Visible = True
        Else
            tempHyperlink.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add "***Visible='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Bind("Error")) ? false:true;***" to the hyperlink tag

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Error" SortExpression="Error">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Error") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="FixHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("AppID", "~/da/Default2.aspx?appid={0}"%>') %>' Visible='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Bind("Error")) ? false:true; %>' >Fix</asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```